# Children categories not shown in dashboard

Tags: categories, hierarchical, children

First of all: it's a strange behavior, but it works.

1) I'm working on a script, so i require the wp-load.php and after that i operate;
2) The scripts creates some categories using wp_insert_term in a hierarchically (Abruzzo > Chieti > Atessa), respectively abruzzo, chieti-abruzzo, chieti-abruzzo-atessa;
3) Here's the strange: it creates the categories good, but as you can see in the screenshot they are not visible in the dashboard. BUT i can use them, they are available (hierarchically) in a post or even to create others category using them as parents. They just don't show (the children) in this single point of the dashboard.

If i create another category and i refresh the page (or even if i delete some), they will be shown. So i think it's something like a database issue.

I read that the wp_insert_term func should be used into/after the 'init' hook.
But as i just said.. i'm in a script.

Workarounds/Solutions?

[image]

Comment: I just noticed there's also the right amount of (not) shown categories: "3 items" on the right, out of the screenshot.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you use to generate these categories please?

Comment: Did you tried to delete the cache after the import? delete_option("{$taxonomy}_children");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by force refreshing the cache (by @passatgt).
i.e., place this line after the insertion:

```
delete_option("{$taxonomy}_children");
```

Thanks!